# How can I refresh the contents of a jsTree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have loaded a jsTree with an AJAX call that returns JSON data. How can I refresh the tree so that it reloads its contents?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Turns out is is as simple as calling:

```
   tree.jstree("refresh");
```

Answer (score 73):

At version 3 you can reload the tree :

```
$('#treeId').jstree(true).settings.core.data = newData;
$('#treeId').jstree(true).refresh();
```

Comment: This works for me, as I JSON data coming from some other function and not AJAX

Comment: I had to set the second parameter of refresh to true: tree.jstree(true).refresh(false, true);

Comment: when using AJAX i had to chain `.url` -> `jstree(true).settings.core.data.url =  "/new/data/url"`

Comment: after refresh nodes get_selected returning values before and after refresh both.
How to selected values after refresh only
var data = JSON.parse(response.data);
$('#treeview').jstree(true).settings.core.data = data;
$('#treeview').jstree(true).refresh(false, true);  

        $("#btn").click(function () {
            console.log($('#treeview').jstree(true).get_selected());
        });

Answer (score 26):

```
var tree = jQuery.jstree._reference("#files");
tree.refresh();
```

or

```
var tree = jQuery.jstree._reference("#files");
var currentNode = tree._get_node(null, false);
var parentNode = tree._get_parent(currentNode);
tree.refresh(parentNode);
```

Comment: I needed to refresh just one specific node. Thanks for this useful tip.

Comment: Yes, I don't like it, even v3 aPI, just like Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 12):

for jstree3 . I use destroy() function and again create tree running jstree() function

Comment: Actually, it's an event, but it helped. `tree.jstree("destroy")`

Comment: @IonicăBizău It's both an event and a method... but that was the clue I needed. You can't call the destroy() method until the tree is initialized, but you can trigger the event.

Answer (score 2):

`$('#treeId').data('jstree', false).empty().jstree(json);`

Comment: It does not work for jstree:3.3.9. You get an error `Uncaught TypeError: $jstree.data(...).empty().jstree is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

my jsTree plug's version is 3.3.15

```
export function jsTreeUpdate(demo_id,treeData) {
  let instance = $('#' + demo_id).jstree(true);
  // set new data
  instance.settings.core.data = treeData;
  //important to refresh the tree, must set the second parameter to true
  instance.refresh(false,true);
}
```

The above code is the important function for update jsTree Node and show the corresponding state of new treeData.

[image]