# Can't replace HTML on element more than once. Rails and JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, jstree

In my app, I have 4 buttons and each button represents a different directory.  Whenever a button is clicked, I make an Ajax call to build a JStree element and display that directory hierarchy to the user.

Everything works fine, but only for the first button that I click on.  Once the JStree element has been built, if I click on another button, the appropriate Ajax calls are performed and the correct responses are received, but the JStree does not update.

I thought perhaps the .html() call was the problem, so I ended up trying .replaceWith() which ended up with the same issue.  I also tried chaining .clear().append(), but that too ended up with the exact same issue.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

---

### **The View**

```
%div
    %h3 Nodes
        %div
            .btn-group{data: {toggle: 'buttons-radio'}}
                %div
                    %button.btn.btn-pill{id: 'abl-test-data-directory-node-1', type: 'button'} Node 1 - loads /home
                %div
                    %button.btn.btn-pill{id: 'abl-test-data-directory-node-2', type: 'button'} Node 2 - loads /boot
                %div
                    %button.btn.btn-pill{id: 'abl-test-data-directory-node-3', type: 'button'} Node 3 - loads /lib
                %div
                    %button.btn.btn-pill{id: 'abl-test-data-directory-node-4', type: 'button'} Node 4 - loads /bin

%div
    %h3 Directory
        #abl-test-data-directory
```

---

### **The Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#abl-test-data-directory-node-1').on('click', function() {
        buildAblTestDataDirectoryAjaxCall(1);
        });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#abl-test-data-directory-node-2').on('click', function() {
        buildAblTestDataDirectoryAjaxCall(2);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#abl-test-data-directory-node-3').on('click', function() {
        buildAblTestDataDirectoryAjaxCall(3);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#abl-test-data-directory-node-4').on('click', function() {
       buildAblTestDataDirectoryAjaxCall(4);
    });
});


function buildAblTestDataDirectoryAjaxCall(nodeIndex){
    $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/fire_ajax/" + nodeIndex.toString(),
    dataType: "script",
    data: nodeIndex,
    error: function(xhr, status){
        alert('There was a problem');
    }
  });
};
```

---

### **The Route**

```
get '/fire_ajax/:nodeID', to: 'ajax#build_test_data_explorer'
```

---

### **The Controller Logic**

```
def build_test_data_explorer
    @folders = directory_hash(get_node_path())

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :abl_test_data_explorer}
    end
end


def get_node_path
   node_id = params[:nodeID]
   node_path = ''

   case node_id
   when "1"
     node_path = '/home'
   when "2"
     node_path = '/boot'
   when "3"
     node_path = '/lib'
   when "4"
     node_path = '/bin'
   else
     node_path = '/home'
   end

   return node_path
end
```

---

**The JS.ERB Logic**

```
function build_abl_test_data_JStree(){
    $("#abl-test-data-directory").html(function(){
        $("#abl-test-data-directory").jstree({ 
            'core' : {
                'data' : <%= @folders.to_json.html_safe %>,
                'themes' : {
                    'name' : 'proton'
                }
            }
        });
    });
};

build_abl_test_data_JStree();
```

Comment: Try to put all `onClick` events in just one `$(document).ready` and check if it works...

Comment: @Laerte if I place all the `onClick` events in a single `$(document).ready` the Ajax events will still fire and retrieve the appropriate responses, however the JStree element NEVER gets updated.  Not even once.

Comment: Haha, sorry @Laerte, I'm a dummy.  Left a line commented out.  Unfortunately, placing all the `onClick()` events in the single `$(document).ready()` still didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to this post :: [Using JStree.destroy()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902502/3183532)

This modification to my JS.ERB code now allows me to dynamically rebuild my JStree whenever I click on the different buttons.

```
function build_abl_test_data_JStree(){
    $("#abl-test-data-directory").html(function(){
        $("#abl-test-data-directory").jstree({ 
            'core' : {
                'check_callback' : true,
                'data' : <%= @folders.to_json.html_safe %>,
                'themes' : {
                    'name' : 'proton'
                }
            }
        });
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#abl-test-data-directory').jstree('destroy');
    build_abl_test_data_JStree();
});
```